# How do I fprintf strings at the beginning of a file in C?

Tags: c, file-io, printf

I wrote this C code segment to read 'n' words into a file using a for loop. A new word should be inserted at the beginning of the file which I reach by using `fseek` everytime.

**Problem**: Only the last scanned word gets placed in the file, while the previous n-1 words do not appear in the file. No errors are shown and the message "done!" get printed 'n' times correctly. Am I doing something wrong?

```
printf("No. OF words: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter word: ");
        scanf("%s",word);
        fprintf(fp,"%s \n",word);
        printf("done!\n\n");
        fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_SET );

    }

    fclose(fp);
```

Comment: In Stream related open of file you cannot overwrite the content. using the write function you can overwrite the content in the file. So you try to open the file with open function.

Comment: do you want input word insert top of file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to append at the beginning of a file. Your current code is overwriting the previous contents of the file.

You basically have two options:

Store all the words in memory and print the to the file in the desired order *or*

Read the entire file, `fseek` to the beginning, print the new word and then print the rest of the contents.

Comment: Yes.  The reason why it's not working (which you don't explicitly mention, and could do with a mention) is that fprintf at position 0 in the file is not inserting, it is overwriting... though I don't really understand why the OP says he sees the first word in the file ... it should be the last.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Sorry, my mistake. the last one shows up ;)

Comment: I wrote the following code to save data present from the current fp position to the end of file. The program crashes after the while loop is entered. Why is that? 
    `FILE *fp,*follow;
    char *savedata[1000];

    void *saveafter()
    {
        char ch;
        int i=0;
        while(ch=getc(fp)!=EOF)
        {
            savedata[i++]=ch;

        }
        savedata[i]='\0';
    }`

Comment: Reading the entire file into memory is not possible/practical if it is large. For example, do you intend to read a 100 GB file into memory just to be able to insert some text at the beginning.

Comment: @user3210476 `=` has lower precedence than `!=`, so you need to add parenthesis around the assignment: `while((ch=getc(fp))!=EOF)`.

Comment: Rather than just the 2 options, I'd suggest another: create another file beginning with the "prepend" data.  Then append the original to the new one.  Once the 2nd file is successfully completely closed, delete the original.  Rename the 2nd file as the first.  This has an advantage of having the original file around should trouble occur creating the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly overwriting the existing words. I've understood the question to be there is a file "file.txt" with some data and you will enter words:
w1, w2, w3, ....., w_n-1, wn which should be written in the file like:
wn, w_n-1, w_n-2, .......w3, w2, w1, original data. Here's a roundabout way to do this:

1. Create a duplicate file "dup1.txt" in the same place as the original and add the new words there.
2. Then add another file where you copy the newly entered words in reverse order. Rename this file as "dup1.txt" to overwrite.
2. Now copy the original data to this file and rename this file "file.txt" to overwrite..

That should do it. In case I'm missing something please do point out.

Answer (score 0):

You can to some thing like this, this will add the new information at the top of your file. SO, the output would be hwllo 9, hellow 8.....hellow 0.

```
            FILE *f;

            for(i=0;i<10;i++)
            {

                f = fopen(cycleInfoFileName11,"at");
                fprintf(f,"hellow : %d\n",i);
                printf("hellow : %d\n",i);
            }
```